# How to use variables from task, outside the task

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I have a code here that used to download pictures from image url then save it in picture library. then there's a button that when clicked, the downloaded image will be displayed. My problem is, i can't display the downloaded image. Here's my code for downloading image:

```
 public async Task Dwnld(Uri uri)
    {
        try
        {

        //filename using global uid to have different names.    
        var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg";



        // download pic
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
        byte[] b = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            //check if download is success
            if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Block.Text = "Download Success";
                Block.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                Ring.IsActive = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Block.Text = "Error Downloading the Image";
                Block.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                await Task.Delay(5000);
                Ring.IsActive = false;
            }
            using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            using (var dw = new DataWriter(stream))
            {
                // write the raw bytes and store
                dw.WriteBytes(b);
                await dw.StoreAsync();
               // write to pictures library
                var storageFile = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync(
                    fileName,
                    CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                using (var storageStream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync(stream.GetInputStreamAt(0), storageStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0));
                }
            }

        }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

then here's my code for the task to display the downloaded image:

```
public async Task Pic()
    {
        var img = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync(fileName);
        var img2 = new BitmapImage();
        using (var pictureStream = await img.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            img2.SetSource(pictureStream);
        }
        Image.Source = img2;

    }
```

as you can see, there's a `fileName` in the `Pic()` which is not declared. My problem now is how can i make the `fileName` be usable to `Pic()` even though it was declared in `Dwnld`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change two methods' signature.

```
public async Task<string> Dwnld(Uri uri)
{
    ...
    await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync(stream.GetInputStreamAt(0), storageStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0));
    return fileName;
```

And

```
public async Task Pic(string fileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up searching several pages from google and tried different keyboard then i came up with the answer.

I declare `private string fileName;`

then erased the `var` in the `dwnld()`. Than you for answering